# Problema con la respuesta en un ASP.NET Web API

Tags: json, datetime, asp.net-web-api

Tengo un ASP.NET Web API que en otros servidores está funcionando correctamente, solo se me está presentando un detalle en un servidor en particular y el problema tiene que ver con las fechas.

Tengo una clase para realizar la conversión de las fechas y es:

```
public class DateTimeConverter : DateTimeConverterBase
   {
      private const string FormatDateTime = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm";

      public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
      {
         writer.WriteValue(((DateTime)value).ToString(FormatDateTime));
      }

      public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
      {
         var value = reader.Value?.ToString();
         try
         {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) && Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(objectType) != null)
            {
               return null;
            }

            return DateTime.Parse(value);
         }
         catch
         {
            throw new ArgumentNullException($"Unexpected token parsing date. Expected String, got {reader.TokenType}.");
         }
      }
   }
```

Cuando realizo la petición al Web API la respuesta que obtengo es esta:

```
[
    {
        "fileName": "VP_1_preview.jpg",
        "lastWriteTime": "06/mm/01/mm/2018 14:06"
    },
    {
        "fileName": "VP_2_preview.jpg",
        "lastWriteTime": "06/mm/01/mm/2018 14:05"
    },
    {
        "fileName": "VP_3_preview.jpg",
        "lastWriteTime": "06/mm/01/mm/2018 14:05"
    },
    {
        "fileName": "VP_4_preview.jpg",
        "lastWriteTime": "06/mm/01/mm/2018 14:04"
    }
]
```

Donde se puede apreciar que al campo lastWriteTime le está agregando los caracteres **mm**.

En el Web.config del Web API también tengo configurado lo siguiente:

```
   <system.web>
      <globalization culture="en-US" uiCulture="en-US" />
      <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1" />
      <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" />
   </system.web>
```

En el archivo WebConfigApi.cs tengo la siguiente configuración:

```
   public static class WebApiConfig
   {
      public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
      {
         // Enable cors
         config.EnableCors();

         // Web API routes
         config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

         config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
             name: "DefaultApi",
             routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });

         var jsonFormatter = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
         jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.DateTimeZoneHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc;
         jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.DateFormatHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.DateFormatHandling.MicrosoftDateFormat;
         jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented;
         jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
         jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Culture = new CultureInfo("en-US")
         {
            NumberFormat = new NumberFormatInfo()
            {
               NumberDecimalDigits = 2,
               NumberDecimalSeparator = "."
            }
         };
         jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new DateTimeConverter());

         config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.UseXmlSerializer = true;
      }
   }
```

También mencionarles que el servidor tiene configurado en la opción Time Zone lo siguiente: (UTC-06:00) Guadalajara, Mexico City, Monterrey

Muchas gracias de antemano por sus comentarios y valiosa ayuda.

Comment: Hola. Que otras diferencias existen entre ese servidor y en los otros que SI funciona? Has revisado la configuración regional?